# Invalid date with Date.parse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

Before a user signs up I require him to create a challenge.

This is challenges_controller:

```
def create
  @challenge = Challenge.new(challenge_params)
  if current_user == nil
    session[:challenge_action] = challenge_params[:action]
    session[:challenge_deadline] = [params["challenge"]["deadline(3i)"], params["challenge"]["deadline(2i)"], params["challenge"]["deadline(1i)"]].join('/')
    redirect_to signup_path
  end
end
```

The parameters are passed through:

```
  Parameters: {"challenge"=>{"action"=>"Run", "deadline"=>"2016-02-29"}, "button"=>""}
```

The `action` and `deadline` parameters are passed as you can see above. But once the new user is created the new challenge is not created:

```
ArgumentError (invalid date):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:33:in `parse'
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:33:in `create'
```

This is users_controller:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      action = session.delete(:challenge_action)
      deadline = session.delete(:challenge_deadline)
      # Create
      if deadline.present?
        @user.challenges.create(
          action: action,  
          deadline: Date.parse(deadline), #Focus of Question
        )
      end
      log_in @user
      redirect_to root_url
  end
```

Now if I change `deadline: Date.parse(deadline)` to `deadline: deadline` then the `challenge` is created upon creating the new user, but the `deadline` isn't saved for some reason:

```
pry(main)> Challenge.last
 id: 1,
 action: "Code",
 deadline: nil,>
```

Comment: `puts session.delete(:challenge_deadline)` please.

Comment: Hi @Anthony. I put it like this: `action = session.delete(:challenge_action)
      deadline = session.delete(:challenge_deadline)
      puts session.delete(:challenge_deadline)` but i didn't see anything so I don't think that's what you meant. But I do think I figured out where the problem is coming from. When I switched to `<%= f.date_select :deadline %>` it worked, but when I switched back to `<%= f.text_field :deadline, id: "update-challenge",%>` it did not. Is there a way to make the latter work? `<script>
  $( "#update-challenge" ).datepicker({
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
  });<script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Challenge object won't save with an invalid deadline value. To use a `text_field` for a date, use the value option.

```
<%= f.text_field :deadline, value: @challenge.deadline.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") %>
```

There is also `date_field` which returns a text field of type Date. The default value is generated by trying to call `strftime("%Y-%m-%d")` on the objects value. You are able to override `strftime("%Y-%m-%d")` by explicitly passing the value option (like above).